# Customizing background color in List of Corrections with the FiXme package

Tags: color, backgrounds, fixme

Suppose I'm using the FiXme package:

```
\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{
    status=draft,
    author= ,
    layout=inline,
    theme=color}
\definecolor{fxnote}{rgb}{0,0,0}    % black
\definecolor{fxwarning}{rgb}{0,0,0} % black
\definecolor{fxerror}{rgb}{0,0,0}   % black
\colorlet{fxnotebg}{green}     % define the background colour:
\colorlet{fxwarningbg}{yellow} % define the background colour:
\colorlet{fxerrorbg}{red}      % define the background colour:
% redefine the layout macro:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\FXLayoutInline[3]{%
  \@fxdocolon {#3}{%
    \@fxuseface {inline}%
    \begingroup
      \sethlcolor{fx#1bg}%
      \color {fx#1}\ignorespaces \hl{#3\@fxcolon #2}%
    \endgroup}}
\makeatother
```

in which I have three different background colors - red, yellow, and green - which are invoked using `\fxerror{...}`, `\fxwarning{...}`, and `\fxnote{...}`, respectively.

How do I make these background colors appear in the List of Corrections? As of now, the notes appear in the traditional way, i.e. black characters on a white background.

Comment: I don't know the command `\sethlcolor`... Where is it from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `\FXLayoutContentsLine` to add the background color also in the List of Fixmes; a possible redefinition would be:

```
\renewcommand*\FXLayoutContentsLine[3]{%
  \iffx@mode@multiuser%
    \fxaddcontentsline{\ignorespaces#3 \protect\sethlcolor{fx#1bg}\color{fx#1}\hl{\fxnotename{#1}: #2}}%
  \else%
    \fxaddcontentsline{\protect\sethlcolor{fx#1bg}\color{fx#1}\hl{\fxnotename{#1}: #2}}%
  \fi}
```

A complete example

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{fixme}
\fxsetup{
    status=draft,
    author= ,
    layout=inline,
    theme=color}
\definecolor{fxnote}{rgb}{0,0,0}    % black
\definecolor{fxwarning}{rgb}{0,0,0} % black
\definecolor{fxerror}{rgb}{0,0,0}   % black
\colorlet{fxnotebg}{green!60}     % define the background colour:
\colorlet{fxwarningbg}{yellow!60} % define the background colour:
\colorlet{fxerrorbg}{red!60}      % define the background colour:
% redefine the layout macro:
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\FXLayoutInline[3]{%
  \@fxdocolon {#3}{%
    \@fxuseface {inline}%
    \begingroup
      \sethlcolor{fx#1bg}%
      \color {fx#1}\ignorespaces \hl{#3\@fxcolon #2}%
    \endgroup}}

\renewcommand*\FXLayoutContentsLine[3]{%
  \iffx@mode@multiuser%
    \fxaddcontentsline{\ignorespaces#3 \protect\sethlcolor{fx#1bg}\color{fx#1}\hl{\fxnotename{#1}: #2}}%
  \else%
    \fxaddcontentsline{\protect\sethlcolor{fx#1bg}\color{fx#1}\hl{\fxnotename{#1}: #2}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listoffixmes

Some regular text
\fxnote{Some test note}
\fxwarning{Some test warning}
\fxnote{Another test note}
\fxnote{Yet another test note}
\fxerror{Some test error}
\fxwarning{Another test warning}
\fxerror{Another test error}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]